# Can I legally use android green robot's 3d model in my game if I made it?

Tags: google-play-games, android-app-licensing

I am making a 3d game in unity, in which i have different characters, and i would like to use Android green robot's 3d model as one of them. I made that model by myself in blender. I just want to make sure there is no problem with any licenses. I couldn't find any info about specifically android robot's 3d model licenses on the internet. So can I use my model in game and publish it on Google play store, or is it still Google's property?[this is my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k23L9.png)

I found some 3d models on the internet, which you are free to use as you want, if you buy them. Does this mean I am free to use my model in game and publish it on Play Store?